# Microsoft Graph Expired Token

Tags: jwt, postman, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token

I'm trying to perform a request in Microsoft Graph like this one with Postman

`https://graph.windows.net/<Tenant>/users?api-version=1.6`

For the Authorization, I'm using Bearer. I'm retrieving the token manually and decoding it here https://jwt.io/ That way I know that it's well formed and that it's not expired yet.

However, I'm getting the following error on the response:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_ExpiredToken",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request."
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You an try Get App-Only Access Token with the Microsoft Graph POST API:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```